# Validação de Senha com Python

Tags: python, django

Tenho a seguinte exigência para validar uma senha no cadastro:

- Tamanho: 10 caracteres
- Maiúscula: 2
- Minúscula: 2
- Número: 1
- Símbolo: 2

Como faço essa verificação com python?

Por enquanto só consegui fazer isso, sendo que a parte da letra maiúscula eu só testei para ver se há alguma na senha:

```
if len(password or ()) < 10:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Senha mínimo 10 caracteres")
    if any(x.isupper() for x in password):
        raise forms.ValidationError("Senha tem letra maiúscula")
    if password and password_confirm:
        if password != password_confirm:
            raise forms.ValidationError("As senhas não conferem")
```

Answer (score 1):

Para esses casos você deve usar expressões regulares.

Olha esse site depois. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

```
import re
from django.forms import forms

def test_password(password):
    minimal_number = 2
    minimal_upper_char = 2
    minimal_lower_char = 2
    minimal_special_char = 1
    minimal_len_char = 10
    if len(password or ()) < minimal_len_char:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Senha tem que ter no mínimo '+str(minimal_len_char)+' caracteres')
    if len(re.findall(r"[A-Z]", password)) < minimal_upper_char:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Senha tem que ter no mínimo '+str(minimal_upper_char)+' letras maiusculas')
    if len(re.findall(r"[a-z]", password)) < minimal_lower_char:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Senha tem que ter no mínimo '+str(minimal_lower_char)+' letras minusculas')
    if len(re.findall(r"[0-9]", password)) < minimal_number:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Senha tem que ter no mínimo '+str(minimal_number)+' numeros')
    if len(re.findall(r"[~`!@#$%^&*()_+=-{};:'><]", password)) < minimal_special_char:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Senha tem que ter no mínimo '+str(minimal_special_char)+' caracteres especiais')
```

Comment: E se o usuário colocar letras acentuadas na senha? A expressão regular não vai pegá-las.

Comment: Obrigada Ytalo, apenas o de caracteres especiais não funcionou... mas entendi a lógica!

Answer (score 1):

Acho que a melhor opção é você escrever o próprio validator e adicionar ele no seu `settings.py`. Aqui na [doc do Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/passwords/#writing-your-own-validator) você pode ver como fazer, mas seria algo tipo esse rascunho que fiz abaixo (adicionei somente um exemplo, faltando implementar todos os métodos para validaçōes):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _


class MyCustomValidator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 10
        self.max_upper_case = 2
        self.max_lower_case = 2
        self.max_int_case = 1
        self.max_symbols_case = 2

    def validate_length_password(self, password):
        if len(self.password) < self.length:
            return True

        return False

    def validate_upper_case(self, password):
        pass

    def validate_lower_case(self, password):
        pass

    def validate_int_case(self, password):
        pass

    def validate_max_symbols_case(self, password):
        pass

    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        if self.validate_length_password(password):
            raise ValidationError(
                _("This password must contain at least "
                    "%(length)d characters."),
                code='password_too_short',
                params={'length': self.length},
            )

    def get_help_text(self):
        return _(
            "Your password must contain at least %(length)d characters."
            % {'length': self.length}
        )
```

Daí lá no seu `settings.py` no `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` você adiciona essa classe, tipo:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'path.onde.ta.o.arquivo.do.seu.validator.finalizando.com.a.classe.MyCustomValidator',
    },
]
```